# kthreaddi very high CPU

Tags: linux, database, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have a dedicated one at DigitalOcean which has hosted a database. I noticed that all the time the CPU is at 100% through the dashboard, so I decided to access the prompt and I found [kthreaddi] consuming all the processing, I have no idea how to solve this, your help is very well connected.

```
1461 www-data  20   0 2737048 2.289g   4204 S 197.7 14.6  16:11.90 [kthreaddi]
 1555 www-data  20   0  303732  36512  26100 S   0.7  0.2   0:13.68 php-fpm7.2
 1060 mysql     20   0 1625968 236968  17204 S   0.3  1.4   0:14.48 mysqld
 1415 www-data  20   0 1473092 1.400g      4 S   0.3  8.9   0:40.31 nsctnncdv
 1703 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3  0.0   0:00.22 kworker/u4:0
 1916 www-data  20   0  303664  34164  23880 S   0.3  0.2   0:05.16 php-fpm7.2
    1 root      20   0  159664   8944   6780 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.62 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't trace nor stop the parent process that was initiating the process `-bash` consuming all of the CPU resources.

But thanks to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/764839/sshd-consuming-100-of-cpu-hundreds-of-processes-will-not-die), it seems we can `kill -STOP <PID>` the process instead of killing it.

It reduced the CPU usage in my case, but is most likely just a temporary solution.

We can also use `htop` to see the running processes, `F6` to order by CPU or Memory, and `F9` to kill (not a solution since the process will be re-created but it's good to know).

And we have `ps faux` too, to see the processes, their parents and the user that created them. We must remove the malicious users.

Answer (score 2):

`kthreaddi` is a crypto miner and you can remove it.

step 1: you should find the executable file link of the mining process

```
ls -l /proc/xxx/exe
```

step 2: Clear the execution files of the mining process.

step 3: Locate the mining process in the process with high CPU consumption and kill the process.

step 4: Check if the mining pool address of the mining program exists in the firewall of your server

- Execute the following command to check whether there are suspicious
  communication addresses and open ports outside the business scope

  ```
    iptables -L -n
  ```
- Execute the following command to remove the malicious mining pool address

  ```
     vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
  ```

step 5: Execute the following command to check whether there are scheduled tasks.

```
      crontab -l
```

step 6: you can use this script to check whether there is a mining virus in the SSH public key to prevent continuous backdoors

```
  #!/bin/bash
    for X in $(cut -f6 -d ':' /etc/passwd |sort |uniq); do
        if [ -s "${X}/.ssh/authorized_keys" ]; then
            echo "### ${X}: "
            cat "${X}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
            echo ""
        fi
    done
```

Comment: On the 1st step I get `ls: cannot read symbolic link '/proc/2/exe': No such file or directory`. I tried replacing with the PID of other processes  but still no luck.